# SOAPUI CorrelationId for Reply in WindowsServices

Tags: xml, web-services, soapui, correlation

I'm newbie to soapUi but I'm trying to test our Request/Reply flow with XMLs.
For  the moment not all integration is finished so for some I need to prepare XMLs and send it by myself.

Flow is as follows:
XML1 is received in system. 
It triggers XML2-request with some messageId. MessageId is stored in DB.
System is waiting for XML2-response with correlationId (correlationId=messageId=the same as was stored in DB and read later).

I need to simulate my XML2-response in order to go futher with my test. I have prepared XML2-response and now I wanted to send it. I have selected queue.

Where can I put this correlationId in soapUi? So correlationId for response can be sent correctly? 
I tried to do it in JMSHeader - JMSCorrealtionID. 
But when I put my correlation into this field and send then after checking in RFHutil if correlation is ok I have message with different correlationId. 
e.g. If I set correlationID=12345 in SoapUI then it is 3132333435 in RFHutil (adding 3 before every digit. ). As a result message cannot be read and nothing more can be checked.

Did anyone had the same problem? Can you help me? Maybe I should use CorrelationId in different way?

Comment: Not sure if I got the entire context. May trying setting dynamic value for `correlationId` using `${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()}`

Answer (score 1):

SOAP UI is used for web services, is using ReplyIdentifier as unique id (not correlationId nor messageId, which are used on MQ).